# textwidth not working on certain lines

Tags: textwidth

I have textwidth set to 80. Result of `:set tw?` is `textwidth=80`.

It works for most lines, but some lines are left with a width of 81 and sometimes 82, even after visually selecting and doing `gq`. This was working perfectly until now. Any idea what could be the issue? Is there some other config that may conflict?

EDIT

A capture showing the problem

[image]

All these lines were formed by a single large line, splitted with `Vgq`. It is seen that the line were the cursor is is perfectly splitted at 80 characters (see the ruler on the bottom right), but the one above has 82 characters, confirmed by placing the cursor on last character

[image]

Comment: This should work with a space closest to the tw. The ability is complicated by 'paste', which could make textwith=0, turning it off. See the conditions in the help under 'paste' and if any of them correlate.

Comment: Does the questionable line have a nbsp? It may APPEAR to be a space; see help for how to highlight them.

Comment: @wbogacz I'm not in paste mode, and I higlighted SpecialKey group which containts nbsp with ':highlight SpecialKey ctermbg=red guibg=red' and didn't see any

Comment: @wbogacz I have added screen captures illustrating the problem

Comment: Could you share the text such that we can try to reproduce your problem?

Comment: I see you are working with a .tex file. That syntax is among the most dense I have read. Maybe something complicated within this.

Comment: If I counted correctly, the value of your `columns` seems to be 84. With the line numbers plus a space using 5 columns the available space for text is 79 columns. Your first screenshot shows you cursor on position 80, but you are using UTF-8 as encoding and you have one non-ASCII letter in that line which is probably encoded with two bytes. So I guess the position in your status bar is measured in bytes, not in characters. This guess is further supported by the second screenshot where the line contains two non-ASCII letters and wraps around by one character. But hard wrapping counts characters

Comment: ... not bytes to determine where to break the line.